# SSO on different sub domains

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, single-sign-on

I have websites hosted on different sub domains.I want to implement SSO on the domain. Using java spring boot 4 (backend) and angularsJS(front end). What is the most proper and secure way?

What we are trying to achieve is to redirect from xyz.example.com (auth server) to one of our application. we have one server containing multiple subdomains on which multiple apps are deployed.

We tried several ways to implement sso but it's not working properly.

**Tried methods:**

1.Redirect from backend by hitting a controller. In this method browser is  throwing a CORS issue while redirecting after authentication.

2. Redirect from frontend using angular.run method where i always redirect to xyz.example.com and make a backend api call to authenticate  the token saved in localstorage

Comment: My first thought would be to use SAML (or similar) to authenticate from each subdomain. It would be seamless from the user perspective (send user out -> immediately redirected back in)

Comment: is there any reference links where i can refer to?